# Автоматический upload связанных файлов PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, развертывание, upload

Здравствуйте, такая проблема, есть 3 файла *.less автогенерит *.css и он генерит *.min.css , можно ли заставить редактор через Deployment при изменении файла *.less автоматически отправлять на сервер не только *.less, а так же автоматом захватывать *.css и *.min.css после генерации?

Answer (score 1):

В настройках Php/WebStorm, нужно установить галочку Upload external changes.
Она определяет будет ли файл автоматически отправляться на сервер при изменениях извне.

```
File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Options > Upload external changes = true
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Понял, исправляюсь